# CA ADS: 3 digits in a pic 9(2) comp field

Tags: ads, mainframe

Strange thing here. During my test of an ADS dialog, numeric value 120 was moved to an index field which was defined as a PIC 9(2) COMP field.

A bit further a field with that index was referenced like this:

Move Field(index) to FIELD2.

‘Index’ was defined as PIC 9(2) COMP and before value 120 was moved to index. The dialog didn’t abended. How come? Do i have to worry about this? Whats the value of ‘index’ after the move of 120???

Thanks

Comment: Is it Cobol ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming **PIC 9(2) COMP** is the **same** in *CA ADS* as in *Cobol* !!!

The answer lies in

- How PIC 9(2) COMP is implemented
- Compiler options used

---

#### Implementation of PIC 9(2) COMP

A **PIC 9(2) COMP** will typically be allocated as either a 1 byte of 2 byte binary integer. A

- A **1** byte binary integer can represent **-128 --> 127** (or 0 --> 255 if a unsigned int is used)
- A **2** byte binary integer can represent **-32000 --> 32000** (or 0 --> 64000 if a unsigned int is used)

So a **PIC 9(2) COMP** can store **120**.

---

#### Compilers

Most (if not all) Cobol compilers have the option to check/correct *Comp overflows* but these options are often **switched off** to improve performance.
I presume it is the same for CA ADS.

Comment: Bruce, Thx for your answer. I did a little test which confirmed your theory.